# New activity is placed halfway down screen

Tags: android

I am making a small little game and I am currently working on a menu for changing settings. I created a new activity and a fragment with PreferenceScreen and one ListPreference. Only problem is when I click a button in the main activity to start the settings activity it is not placed at the top of the screen, it is placed halfway down the screen. I would like this activity to be at the top of the screen, how can I do this?

Screenshot: http://i68.tinypic.com/288cue.png
(Need 10 reputation to post directly)

res/xml/preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:dependency="pref_sync"
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:entries="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_syncConnectionTypes_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

SettingsActivity:

```
package com.example.eiria.pressit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

SettingsFragment:

```
package com.example.eiria.pressit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created activity_settings.xml and set the root view to a vertical LinearLayout with width and height set to 1000dp. Even though it is not really a good one, this was the only working solution I found.

**EDIT:**
I have a button in the settings activity that I wanted to align at the bottom of the screen. layout_gravity="bottom" did not work, and would go off the screen because the LinearLayout height is 1000dp anyways. So I changed to RelativeLayout and set the width and height to match_parent, then set the button's alignParentBottom to true and boom, the settings activity fills the whole screen height. Unfortunately, setting the button's alignParentLeft/Start or alignParentRight/End to true does not make the settings activity fill the whole screen width.